# How to Setup Angular Routing URL Prepending?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, routes

I have an Angular 14 application setup with Node and am trying to seperate user and admin space. An example for this would be google.com, then cloud.google.com and console.cloud.google.com. How would I go about setting this up?

My goals:

- example.com as user space
- console.example.com as admin space

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are looking for are two different subdomains. You can either accomplish this by setting the corresponding A-records (with different IPs) where you host the DNS for your website. OR the better way is to deploy a reverse proxy (like nginx) and then manage your routing there.